# Mutually exclusive switch parameters

Tags: powershell

The function has one required parameter, -Path, and two other mutually exclusive switches. This is not the real function, but a MRE (Minimal Reproducable Example). The default operation is to copy the file to a known location and then remove it.

```
Do-TheFile [-Path] <String[]> [[-Copy] | [-Remove]]
    -Path = filename is mandatory
    -CopyOnly = only copy the file, cannot be used with -Remove
    -RemoveOnly = only remove the file, cannot be used with -Copy
```

This is the current code.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [string[]]$Path

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='CopyOnly')]
    [switch]$CopyOnly

    ,[Parameter(Mandatory=$false ,ParameterSetName='RemoveOnly')]
    [switch]$RemoveOnly
)
```

The console allows me to specify both -CopyOnly and -RemoveOnly. My expectation was that the console would not permit me to enter both -CopyOnly and -RemoveOnly because they are in different ParameterSets. How can I specify these ParameterSets so that -Copy and -Remove are mutually exclusive?

```
PS C:\src\t> Do-TheFile -Path t.txt -CopyOnly -RemoveOnly
Do-TheFile: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.
```

Comment: when i test your param block in a function, it gives me both switches _as expected_ until i choose one. after that, the other is NOT available. do you see different behavior?

Comment: You are doing it correctly. As Lee mentionned, both set are available unti you choose one. Your sample error message  is already stating that fact. The `Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.` message specifically indicate that you attempted to run a command with parameter from more than one set. Even though there is nothing to prevent you to write it, the second option should not show in your intellisense as soon as you entered the first one.

Comment: @SagePourpre, but -RemoveOnly is showing up. Typing `Do-TheFile -Path t.txt -CopyOnly -re<tab>` autocompletes it to `-RemoveOnly`. Does that indicate that something is not installed or configured correctly? If so, what?

Comment: You may want to see https://powershell.org/forums/topic/powershell-function-forcing-only-one-switch/

Comment: @NekoMusume, that appears to be relevant. It appears that PowerShell will not take care of that. The developer must code the exclusivity into their source. This seems like something PowerShell should do.

Comment: @lit I spoke too fast. This is default behavior stuff. Both ISE / VSCode have similar behavior on this. ISE will indeed autocomplete on TAB the parameter but it won't show it in the intellisense. If you press CTRL + Space again though, intellisense will reopen now showing remove only. 

VSCode won't show the parameter either but if you type most characters, it will finally show up. 

So the parameters for the concurrent parameter set are hidden by default but can be forced in the intellisense. That being said, executing the command will always fail with your original error message.

Comment: Regarding Neko link, I don't think this is relevant to your actual problem. Powershell already handle the "throw" for you since you are using parameterset. Your command, when you fill both parameters, is never executed. Throw is not required and won't change anything in your case.

Comment: @SagePourpre, yes, I just tried in the code and noticed the exception you mention even before my code begins.I am using PowerShell Console, not ISE or VS Code. I still am thinking the Console (and ISE and VS Code) should handle this better.

Comment: Before the Param add:  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'CopyOnly')]

Comment: @RetiredGeek, the default operation (without -CopyOnly or -RemoveOnly) is to do both copy and remove.

Comment: Then just remove the DefaultParameterSetName, you still need the CmdletBinding decoration to make the parameter sets work correctly in my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with the others here.

Your code works, as written when using IntelliSense, but PowerShell will not stop you from typing in other valid switches/variables/property names (in either the consolehost, ISE, VSCode, Visual Studio, etc...), that does not mean it would work just because you typed both.

Why make two switches, when you only want to use one option at a time, no matter what.
Just use a simple validation set.

```
Function Test-MyFunctionTest
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,  Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateSet('CopyOnly', 'RemoveOnly')]
        [string]$FileAction
    )

}

# Results
<#
Test-MyFunctionTest -Path $PWD -FileAction CopyOnly
Test-MyFunctionTest -Path $PWD -FileAction RemoveOnly
#>
```

Otherwise, as you have discovered, you have to code this up yourself. For example:

```
Function Test-MyFunctionTestAgain
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Path,
        [switch]$RemoveOnly
    )

    If($RemoveOnly.IsPresent)
    {'Do the remove action'}
    Else {'Do the copy action'}
}

Test-MyFunctionTestAgain -Path $PWD
# Results
<#
Do the copy action
#>

Test-MyFunctionTestAgain -Path $PWD -RemoveOnly
# Results
<#
Do the remove action
#>
```

***Update***

As for this...

> "I agree that this could work. Although, the default operation (using
> no switches) is to both Copy and Remove."

... then this...

```
Function Test-MyFunctionTestMore
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,  Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][ValidateSet('CopyAndRemove', 'CopyOnly', 'RemoveOnly')]
        [string]$FileAction = 'CopyAndRemove'
    )

    Switch ($FileAction)
    {
        CopyAndRemove {'Do the copy and remove action'}
        CopyOnly      {'Do the copy only action'}
        RemoveOnly    {'Do the remove only action'}
    }
}


Test-MyFunctionTestMore -Path $PWD
# Results
<#
Do the copy and remove action
#>
Test-MyFunctionTestMore -Path $PWD -FileAction CopyOnly
# Results
<#
Do the copy only action
#>
Test-MyFunctionTestMore -Path $PWD -FileAction RemoveOnly
# Results
<#
Do the remove only action
#>
```

Or this way, if you are really yearning just to have a switch ;-} ...

```
Function Test-MyFunctionTestSwitch
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string[]]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][ValidateSet('CopyAndRemove', 'CopyOnly', 'RemoveOnly')]
        [string]$FileAction = 'CopyAndRemove',
        [switch]$RemoveOnly
    )

    If($RemoveOnly.IsPresent)
    {
        $FileAction = 'RemoveOnly'
        'Do the remove only action'
    }
    ElseIf ($FileAction -eq 'CopyOnly')
    {'Do the copy only action'}
    Else{'Do the copy and remove action'}
}

Test-MyFunctionTestSwitch -Path $PWD
# Results
<#
Do the copy and remove action
#>

Test-MyFunctionTestSwitch -Path $PWD -FileAction CopyOnly
# Results
<#
Do the copy only action
#>

Test-MyFunctionTestSwitch -Path $PWD -RemoveOnly
# Results
<#
Do the remove only action
#>
```

Lastly as a point of note:

Trying to emulate some other tools actions, or expecting PowerShell to natively emulate some other tools actions, params, etc., really should not be an expectation.

If you believe PowerShell should have a specific feature, then the option is to [submit it to the PowerShell team](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), to have it upvoted by others for work/inclusion or since PowerShell is open-sourced, you can tool it up and submit it for review/approval of commit.

Comment: I agree that this could work. Although, the default operation (using no switches) is to both Copy and Remove. The reason for having multiple operation switches is to emulate an existing program invocation. This re-implementation of an existing program in PowerShell will run on machines for which the original program is not available. Users of the program know it well and will find having separate command line switches familiar.

Answer (score 2):

In contemporary versions of PowerShell, ParameterSets are mutually exclusive.

```
    function greet {
        Param(
          [String]
          $Name = "World",
          [Parameter(ParameterSetName="intro")]
          [Switch]
          $Hello,
          [Parameter(ParameterSetName="outro")]
          [Switch]
          $Farewell
        )

        if ($Hello) {
          echo "Hello, $Name!"
        } elseif ($Farewell) {
          echo "Farewell, $Name!"
        } else {
          echo "What's up, $Name"
        }
    }
```

This results in the split-groupings that you often see in MS cmdlets:

```
> greet -?

NAME
    greet

SYNTAX
    greet [-Name <string>] [-Hello] [<CommonParameters>]

    greet [-Name <string>] [-Farewell] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Doing this requires that the user or the script identify which ParameterSet should be used.

```
greet -Name "Bob"
> greet -Name "Bob"
greet: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.
```

This is trying to tell the user they weren't specific enough. See [DefaultParameterSetName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets) for how to set it from the script:

> There is a limit of 32 parameter sets. When multiple parameter sets are defined, the DefaultParameterSetName keyword of the CmdletBinding attribute specifies the default parameter set. PowerShell uses the default parameter set when it can't determine the parameter set to use based on the information provided to the command.

Answer (score 1):

@[Postanote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote)'s answer is great and I will prefer it.

However, as @[kfsone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257645/kfsone) underlined, `DefaultParameterSetName` can achieve this with your two switches if you add a `ParameterSetName` for `$Path` only and set it as default :

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='CopyAndRemove')]
param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
   [Parameter(ParameterSetName='CopyAndRemove')]
   [Parameter(ParameterSetName='CopyOnly')]
   [Parameter(ParameterSetName='RemoveOnly')]
   [string[]]$Path,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='CopyOnly')]
   [switch]$CopyOnly,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$false ,ParameterSetName='RemoveOnly')]
   [switch]$RemoveOnly
)
$Path
$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
```

Comment: This is good. As you say, @postanote's answer is maybe better from a Powershell idiomatic perspective, but it's still good to support a format that is so common among other tools.